# How can I display two single quotes in LaTeX?

Tags: punctuation, syntax

I need to display two single quotes without anything between them (I'm preparing computer science lecture slides and I want to display `'\''`), but of course LaTeX wants to translate `''` to closing double quotes.

What can I do to bypass what is now a limitation for me?

Comment: This question triggered a lot of different suggestions and I learned a lot from most of them... I elected the answer with the solution I actually chose, but many of them would have worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on whether you need ordinary or "straight" (i.e., perfectly vertical) single quotes, you could use a verbatim environment or some of the macros of the `textcomp` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} % for \Verb instruction
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textquotesingle
\begin{document}
\Verb+'\''+

\texttt{\textquotesingle\textbackslash\textquotesingle\textquotesingle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, useful set of suggestions. I went for verbatim, I just didn't know I could use verbatim stuff in-line.

Answer (score 6):

Put a `{}` between the quotes:

```
'\textbackslash'{}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `'\null'` or `'\hspace{0pt}'` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a single left quote using `\textquoteleft` and a single right quote using `\textquoteright`, so

```
\textquoteleft\textquoteright
```